# bytes to image converting error

Tags: c#, image, stream, byte

am crteating a client server application
and the client will ask the server for a certain image, and the server will send it to the client

when the client receive it , it will show it in a picturebox

so this is my code

```
string line = null;
            line = textBox3.Text;
            socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line)); 
            data = new byte[1024];
            dataSize = socket.Receive(data);
            //string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, dataSize);
            //           textBox4.Text = s;
            Image newImage;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data,0,dataSize)) 
            { 

                ms.Write(data,0,dataSize); 

                newImage = Image.FromStream(ms,true); //HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM

            }


            pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
        }
```

then it returns an error called, Parameter is not valid, so i dont know what wrong in here?

Comment: "It" doesn't "return" an error at all.  Something in there throws an exception, and the first thing you should do is work out which function it is which is throwing the exception.  It's possible to waste hours looking at the wrong bit of code unless you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to believe the image is less than 1KB in size. Have bigger buffer:

```
 data = new byte[1024 * 500]; //limit to 500KB
```

Having buffer smaller than the actual size of the image probably results in an incomplete data which is indeed invalid stream for the image.

Comment: That still won't work correctly since TCP is a stream not packet based protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the memory stream's position back to the start after writing to it:

```
...
ms.Write(data,0,dataSize); 
ms.Position = 0;
newImage = Image.FromStream(ms,true); //HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your network code is buggy in two ways:

1) If the data is >1024 bytes it won't work at all
2) If the incoming data gets fragmented it's break (One Send call does NOT map to one Receive call). TCP is a stream not packet based protocol.

To fix it first write the bytesize of the image, and when reading read until you have enough bytes and only then construct the image from the bytes.